# Problem with implementing a dialogue system in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my own visual novel in Unity. 
I made a text manager script to load the text files and to read them correctly and a text box script to load the text onto the text box. In my hierachy I made two objects, one for the text box script and the other for the dialogue manager. (DialogueParserObj)
My goal was it to put the text file into the text box, which is seen as the dialogue string variable in the TextBox script so you could see the actual text file in the dialogue box I have marked. But it remains empty, and I don't know why and I don't get any errors.

I would really appreciate your help or other suggestions to go about a well structured dialogue system!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DialogueBox : MonoBehaviour
{
TextManager parser;
public string dialogue;
int lineNum;

public GUIStyle customStyle;

void Start()
{
dialogue = "";
parser = GameObject.Find("DialogueParserObj").GetComponent<TextManager>();               
lineNum = 0;
 }


  void Update()
  {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
    {
        dialogue = parser.GetContent(lineNum);
        lineNum++;
   }
  }

  void OnGUI()
  {
      dialogue = GUI.TextField(new Rect(100, 400, 600, 200), dialogue,  customStyle);             
  } 







      using System.Collections;
      using System.Collections.Generic;
      using System.IO;
      using UnityEngine;
      using UnityEngine.UI; 


      public class TextManager : MonoBehaviour
      {


     string readPath;
      List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
      List<DialogueLine> lines = new List<DialogueLine>();



      struct DialogueLine
      {
          public string name;
          public string content;
       public int pose;

       public DialogueLine(string n, string c, int p)
       {
           name = n;
           content = c;
           pose = p;
       }
   }


   void Start()
   {
       readPath = Application.dataPath + "/text.txt";
       ReadFile(readPath);

   }


public string GetName(int lineNumber)
   {
       if (lineNumber < lines.Count)
       {
           return lines[lineNumber].name;
       }

       return "";
   }

   public string GetContent(int lineNumber)
   {
       if (lineNumber < lines.Count)
       {
           return lines[lineNumber].content;
       }

       return "";
   }

   public int GePose(int lineNumber)
   {
       if (lineNumber < lines.Count)
       {
           return lines[lineNumber].pose;
       }

       return 0;
   }
   void ReadFile(string filePath)
   {
       StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filePath);

       while (!r.EndOfStream)
       {
           string line = r.ReadLine();


           if (line != null)
           {
               string[] lineValues = line.Split('|');
               DialogueLine lineEntry = new DialogueLine(lineValues[0],    lineValues[1], int.Parse (lineValues [2]));
               stringList.Add(line); 
           }

       }

       r.Close();
   }
```

[image: DialogueBoxProblem]

Comment: In general don't use `+ "/"` for file paths. Rather use `Path.Combine` which automatically Inserts the correct path separators according to the executing platform

Comment: Take a look at the ink system, its premade, then you already have "options" for buttons and the "text" for the dialogue as/whatever you neeed it comes built in with options and fancyness and, its free.

Comment: Debug your code step by step .. you seem to get no lines so you get an empty string ..

Comment: How does your TextManager work?